Equivalent forms of heavy ball method
I am looking at https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~brecht/cs726docs/HeavyBallLinear.pdf
which says one could write
$$
\begin{align*}
p_{k} & = - \nabla f(x_{k}) + \beta_{k} p_{k-1} \\
x_{k+1} & = x_{k} + \eta_{k} p_{k}
\end{align*}
$$
as
$$
x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \eta_k \nabla f(x_k) + \beta_k (x_k - x_{k-1})
$$
The latter form does seem like the more common form of the heavy ball method, but there seems to be a problem of such a statement, because
$$
x_{k} - x_{k-1} = \eta_{k-1} p_{k-1} \iff p_{k-1} = \frac{x_k - x_{k-1}}{\eta_{k-1}}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} & = x_{k} + \eta_k p_k \\
& = x_{k} + \eta_k \left( - \nabla f(x_{k}) + \beta_{k} p_{k-1} \right) \\
& = x_{k} - \eta_k  \nabla f(x_{k}) + \eta_k \beta_{k} p_{k-1}  \\
& = x_{k} - \eta_k  \nabla f(x_{k}) + \eta_k \beta_{k}  \left( \frac{x_k - x_{k-1}}{\eta_{k-1}} \right)
\end{align*}
$$
which really requires $\eta_k = \eta_{k-1}$ to be true, i.e. a constant step-size/learning rate. I did see this equivalency statement coming from other places, and so I am trying to figure out whether I've made any mistakes here.
